# Trying to query data where string has a single quote

Tags: procedure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, single-quotes

Trying to go through a list of values where there might be one with a single quote in it. When I try to pass it through a function, it fails.

It gives the error,

```
Execution error in store procedure REPORT_PRESENTATION_DATA: SQL compilation error: parse error line 1 at position 164 near '<EOF>'. syntax error line 1 at position 158 unexpected 't'. At Statement.execute, line 90 position 41
```

I then add 
myCommonValue = myCommonValue.replace("'","''"); 
but now get the error,

```
JavaScript execution error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null in REPORT_PRESENTATION_DATA at ' myCommonValue = myCommonValue.replace("'","''");' position 36 stackstrace: REPORT_PRESENTATION_DATA line: 85
```

Here's a code sample:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_SNOWFLAKE_PROCEDURE()
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$

    ...

    sqlText = ` SELECT fields FROM MYTABLE `;
    statement = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText });
    const rs = statement.execute();

    let results = [];
    while (rs.next()) {
        let myColumnValue = rs.getColumnValue(1);
        myColumnValue = myColumnValue.replace("'","''");

        // Using the column value which could contain a single quote in the string,
        // get a second result set. IE: "gov't" may be the string value passed into Query_GroupValues
        sqlText = ` SELECT * FROM table(Query_GroupValues('${startdate}', '${enddate}', ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('${myColumnValue}'))) `;
        statement = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText });
        const rsTableValue = statement.execute();

        if (statement.getRowCount() > 0) {
            let myValue = rsTableValue.getColumnValue(1);

            struct = {
                attributes: {
                    value: myValue
                }
            }

            results.push(struct);
        }
    }

    ...

$$;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like myColumnValue was null when it's replace() method was invoked.  Adding a guard should fix it.  For Example: `if (myColumnValue!=null) myColumnValue = myColumnValue.replace("'","''");`